# String concatenation and string repetition operators

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand why does the following:

```
say 4 x 2.5 * 2;
```

produce

```
88
```

instead of

```
44444
```

as the following:

```
say 4 x (2.5 * 2);
```

The way I tried to explain the second one is that since operator x expects a number as right argument 2.5 * 2 gets computed into number 5 and then 4 is treated as string which yields "44444".  But I can't explain the 1st one!  Changing it to print does not matter, either.

```
print 4 x 2.5 * 2 . "\n"
```

also gives

```
88
```

I am not about to write such code, of course.  I'm just trying to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The repetition operator `x` and the multiplication `*` have the [same precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity). Both are also left-associative. Therefore, the correct parenthezisation for

```
4 x 2.5 * 2
```

is

```
(4 x 2.5) * 2
```

Because the 2nd argument for `x` must be an integer, this is equivalent to

```
(4 x 2) * 2
```

Which does `"44" * 2`. There we have our `88`.

If in doubt, use explicit parens to make your intentions clear to the compiler:

```
say 4 x (2.5 * 2);
```

Comment: Because this is actually quite confusing (I walked into this trap a few times), this could be considered some form of a bug. Anyway, Perl6 [changes the precedence](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S03.html#Operator_precedence) so that your unmodified code would have run as expected.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that 4 + 2 * 3 isn't 18 is some form of a bug (precedence rules are a bug).  SmallTalk (and APL, in reverse) have fixed the bug.